# How to show/hide DIV on selection of drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have selection in dropdown menu of 4 items .
I want hide all the DIV initially , unless any option is selected. 
And on selection any of the above option I want to display only that DIV.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself? This isn't a cod-writing service. Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and your relevant code, so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".drop-down-menu").toggle();
    $(".drop-down-menu-button").click(function() {
        $(".drop-down-menu").toggle();
        $(".hide").toggle();
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="drop-down-menu-button">Hide The Text And Toggle The Menu</button>

<ul class="drop-down-menu">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>

<div class="hide">
 <h1>Hide Me By Clicking the button</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "*Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem*". Answering low-quality questions just encourages more off-topic and poor quality questions. Save your well-intentioned efforts for questions that meet the guidelines and show some effort on the part of the person asking.